# What is the best practice to recover from a .war file into a web application

Tags: java, eclipse

Our organization invested in a java web application that we want to be able to develop upon. Unfortunately last developer left with only the .war file. How can we recover some of the class files, change them then redeploy as war again. We tried to do that in Eclipse but after importing as war, we could not configure build path. (which in my understanding, the war was imported as static project). I could not find "Convert to dynamic project" as said in eclipse help document.

Answer (score 3):

A .jar/.war file is compressed using the ZIP format. You can decompress it using any zip utility like WinZIP/WinRAR/etc. and then use your favorite decompiler on the .class files.

Answer (score 0):

[Java Decompiler](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/) is the best I've ever come across. You could open your entire war with this.

Answer (score 0):

There is another option for special cases: Have a look at `aspectj`, so you can

- weave in additional code around method calls to fix bugs etc.
- add fields or methods etc.

It works on the *byte code level* (it works with `.class` files).

As for the long run, grab what you recover using a decompiler, and start to replace class files step by step.